# Flutter why is Navigator changing colour of Scaffold beneath transparent Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, transparency, flutter-bottomnavigation

**Q) Why in [this DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=95e0d2158d518965a8aebb817c79b50c) is the transparent page not showing solid blue like the `BottomNavigationBar`, which is also transparent?**

Edit: This is just to illustrate the problem that is occurring on my iOS device + simulator.

Edit2: This was working fine in Flutter V2, now not so much in Flutter V3!

- Explanation:

I've got a persistent `BottomNavigationBar` and I'm wrapping each tab's page with its own 'Navigator', so I can have individual page stacks. That's all fine.

However, in this example, I want my pages to be transparent and show the colour behind, which is wrapping the whole screen.

- To demonstrate:

If you go to line 156 - you can toggle between: `return _page!;` and `return Visibility(...`

**Screenshot bad:**

[image]

**Screenshot good:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a regression bug from v2 to v3. Github issue here:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/105738

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be like a problem with dartpad renderer. I ran your code in Android studio and both returned the same UI. Adding images for your reference[image: preview1]

[image: preview2]

Comment: It's not the dartpad renderer as I have the same issue on iOS devices.  I just used dartpad to show the code running.  I suspect you're on V2+ flutter, not V3?

Comment: Yeah I am on V2. You are right. I used an iOS simulator to check it. Try building it on another device please.

Comment: Same on Android device (pixel 4a Android 12)

Comment: Instead of CupertinoPageRoute if you add MaterialPageRoute it give the same result.

Comment: Yep - same thing.